# Copy within multiple folders

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I currently have the following code on the command line `for i in *.wav; do cp text.txt $i.txt; done` which copies a text file for each wav file, but renames the text file so that it matches the wav file. Is there a way to do this for multiple folders within one directory at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find for that:

```
find your_folder -name '*.wav -exec cp text.txt {}.txt \;
```

This will create text files for all WAVs in `your_folder`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, my backslash key isn't currently working, so I can't test this. I do have an additional question. Each of the text files is labeled for the folder name (which is a number between 0 and 51). Can I write a regex for the name of the text file? `/[0-9]?[0-9]/.txt`

Comment: You might try starting a bash subshell with readline editing disabled: `bash --noediting`. This will allow you to work with backslashes if there's a problematic keybinding.

Comment: Also, I'm not clear on the regex comment, but, e.g.  `touch {0..51}.txt` would create .txt files from 0 to 51.

Comment: The text files already exist. So, there is a directory called "WavFiles" and then there are subdirectories numbered 0 through 51, and within those folders, there are text files that have the same name as the folder. As such, I'm trying to write a command that will copy that text file (the name will change) within each folder for a given directory.

Comment: I can finally type a backslash! I tried this command with a regex and it doesn't seem to work.